# How pandas diff handles bool values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean

Here is the result of explicit subtract

```
>> True - False
1
>> False - True
-1
```

And here is the result of [pandas.Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
>> x = pd.Series([True,False,True])
>> x.diff()

0     NaN
1    True
2    True
dtype: object
```

However, I expected to get

```
0     NaN
1      -1
2       1
dtype: object
```

Why the results differ and how pandas treats bool in this case?

Comment: I suspect this is coming from underlying Numpy behavior aswell `np.diff(x.values)`

Comment: @JohnGalt appears to correct. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9251   This is a numpy feature.  What should False - True equal?  To make sure, cast False as 0 and True as 1 then subtract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [series.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py)

```
result = algorithms.diff(_values_from_object(self), periods)
```

From [algorithms.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/algorithms.py)

```
out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
```

Thus, it results in a subtraction of 2 numpy boolean arrays.

And as it was pointed in the comments, numpy subtracts boolean values in its own way that is different from native python subtraction

```
>> np.array([True, False]) - np.array([False, True])
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I think, you should also raise this issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/ for the maintainers notice and response. And, just to note, `x - x.shift()` equivalent of `x.diff()` works fine.

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks for suggestion, here is the [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17294).